# How to push a SP list item to another SP list in a different site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-2016

I have a SharePoint 2010 list on an external site for contractors to submit their applications. Currently, it uses an Infopath form and sends applications through emails with a XML version of Infopath form as attachment. My coworker then copies and pastes the application fields to a separate SP list on our internal site (SP 2016), where we track progresses. This is a tedious/intensive process. So, we would like to automate the process where we want push new applications (SP list items) to the SP list on the internal site. How do I do that or do you have any alternative recommendations?

Here could be some useful information:

- Custom code is not allowed as IT has locked it down
- Form was created with Infopath
- Workflows are not allowed on the external site
- Both sites are in different site collections
- REST/SOAP services are locked down
- No access to SharePoint Designer
- After we make changes to the internal SP list, we do not need to reflect the changes on our external site
- XML version of the Infopath form is emailed to us (can we make use of the XML file?)
- We are using Windows 7; external site is using SP 2010 and internal site is using SP 2016

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your existing infopath form which is hosted in external SharePoint 2010 has data connection - now you can change the data connection file URL which will point to your new SharePoint 2016 site - then your existing external form will continue to work without changing anything. We have implemented using the same approach it worked.

If the above does not work for you, you may convert that infopath form into Nintex live for external access as you have mentioned above - you have lot of limitation for other approaches.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! Do you have the step-by-step? I've just tried it and it doesn't look like it's doing its job.. maybe I configured it incorrectly? Thanks so much!

Comment: @HuorCulnamo - You need go to your all site content page, there you need to search Data Connection library - once you identify the data connection library - you need to download that particular data connection file(.udcx) and need to change the URL there - then upload back to the same location. While changing the URL - make sure the /_layouts/15 adding to the url otherwise in SP2016 url will not work.

Comment: @HuorCulnamo : You can refer the below URL: 
https://threewill.com/updating-universal-data-connection-xml-udcx-files-after-a-sharepoint-migration/ 
 https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224041&seqNum=3 
 https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73312/how-to-change-connection-source-in-data-connections-in-infopath-forms

Comment: @HuorCulnamo : You can find the exclusive infopath related problem and solution in the below site: https://www.infopathdev.com/forums